# Should I specify the userId in the REST URL structure?

Tags: rest, http, authentication, url

Basically, one feature of my app is to retrieve the logged user's friends.

Actually, I hesitate between both kind of endpoints:

1. GET /api/users/friends
2. GET /api/users/:userId/friends

Using 1, `userId` would be reachable through the authentication token.
Using 2, server would have to additionally check for the correspondance between the passed `userId`, and the logged user id specified in the auth token so that it avoids any malicious access to other user data, like friends.

So 1 should be enough, but it doesn't sound like a standard rest url.

What is a good practice?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The first solution has a benefit of avoiding data duplication. The request plainly means:

> Hello, I'm John. Give me the list of **my** friends.

If possible, I would even shorten it to `GET /api/friends`.

On the other hand, if you expect to be able to access friends of other users, the second solution appears the good one. The request means:

> Hello, I'm John. Give me the list of friends of John.

but can also be:

> Hello, I'm John. Give me the list of friends of Mary.

For instance, one situation where such change can be possible is where a person can find her own friends, but also friends of her friends.

Comment: Neat answer, thanks. You've just confirmed what I thought ;)

Comment: I would go a step further. With `GET /api/friends` I would rename it `GET /api/myFriends`. From a discoverability point of view its more self documenting. Further, with REST its useful to think about how a browser/proxy cache would handle it. With `GET /api/myFriends` it is entirely possible to have a bug where you display the wrong friends due to caching.

Comment: There is one catch when you use relative URIs (relative to the logged in user) certain scenarios become awkward to implement. Particularly when you want to let a user impersonate another, such as a support user that needs to login and see everything as another user. If he is logged in as the support user, but tries to impersonate a user he wants to help, he is going to end up looking at his own friends, not the user's he is trying to help.

Answer (score 3):

Rest Api's must be hypertext driven ! As you would click from one link to another in a standard html page.

An URL is a unique identifier to a resource. Having an url representing more than one resource is in total disacordance with ReST.

With your example, the following url :

```
/api/users/:userId
```

should have a link in its response to the :userId friends url

Roy Fielding's dissertation contains a set of constraints needed to comply to ReST.

http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven
http://fr.slideshare.net/rnewton/2013-06q-connycrestfulwebapis
http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm